# URL re-write character truncate issue php .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

**Requirement** 
To configure a optional multi-parameter url pattern in .htacess file.

**Issue Description**
**Parameter values are being truncated as below (check the output url, it's values against the keys [api=item&act=s] )** 
**Input :** http://localhost/nFoodApp/items/get 
**Output URL :** 
 /nFoodApp/index.php?api=item&act=s&menu=g&category=e&type=t&item=

**Expected Output based on Parameter passed** 
**Input :** http://localhost/nFoodApp/items/get 
**Output URL :** /nFoodApp/index.php?api=items&act=get&menu=&category=&type=&item=

OR

**Input :** nFoodApp/items/get/1 
**Output URL :** /nFoodApp/index.php?api=items&act=get&menu=1&category=&type=&item=

OR

**Input :** nFoodApp/items/get/1/1 
**Output URL :** /nFoodApp/index.php?api=items&act=get&menu=1&category=1&type=&item=

**My .htacess File**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /nFoodApp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/?(.*)$ index.php?api=$1&act=$2&menu=$3&category=$4&type=$5&item=$6 [L,QSA]
```

For researchers, the above is the htacess file created after hours of googling, trials and run's with all possible combinations/patterns using *.()[]/$^[L,QSA,R=301,NC], googling, however, could not resolve the issue yet.

Working fine if all parameters passed 
**Input with all parameter:** //localhost/nFoodApp/items/get/1/1/1/1
**Output:** api=items&act=get&menu=1&category=1&type=1&item=

Might not be able to explain clearly the issue, but the examples clearly state the issue and the config's as shown in the .htaccess snippet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May i know, what exactly is unclear, Looks pretty straight forward with example ?

Comment: thanks for editing the view of the .htaccess file. looking better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your last line, using this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/.]+)(?:/([^/.]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/(.*))?)?)?)?)?$ index.php?api=$1&act=$2&menu=$3&category=$4&type=$5&item=$6 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Croises, it works as expected. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I was able to help a little.

Comment: Honestly, wasn't a little for me, took me half a night and a day with trials and runs, resolving but could not resolve it. Anyways thanks again, always keep helping, makes this forum a great place to learn and share...

Comment: In programming, it's often like that. When you know, it's easy, but before that seemed impossible. And this forum is really perfect for that.